# Code is taking half of my input

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am in a programming class to learn C++. We had to work on a if and else statement problem. Below is my code, and I am trying to figure out why it is halving it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   int age;
   double price;
   char category;
   double finalPrice;

   cin >> price;
   cin >> age;
   cin >> category;

if (age <= 0) {
   cout << "Wrong input";
   }
if (age > 0 && age <= 5) {
   if (category != 'A' || 'a') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 100)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
   }

else if(category == 'A' || 'a') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 0)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
   }
}

if (age > 5 && age <= 12) {
   if (category != 'B' || 'b') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 50)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
   }
else if(category == 'B' || 'b') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 0)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
      }   
   }

if (age > 12 && age <= 26) {
   if (category != 'C' || 'c') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 60)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
   }
else if(category == 'C' || 'c') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 0)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
      }      
}

if (age > 26 && age <= 60) {
   if (category != 'D' || 'd') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 70)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
   }
else if(category == 'D' || 'd') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 0)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
   }
}

if (age > 60) {
   if (category != 'E' || 'e') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 80)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
   }
else if(category == 'E' || 'e') {
      finalPrice = price - (( price * 0)/100);
      cout << fixed;
      cout << setprecision(2) << finalPrice;
      }      
}

return 0;
}
```

So above is my code for a assignment for school.

When I enter the values **14.56 25 C**
I get an output of **5.8.2**

However my expected output should just be **14.56**

Am I just overseeing something? I don't get how it is even getting half.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(category != 'A' || 'a')`, etc -

I suspect you mean "category is not 'A' or 'a'"; Try `((category != 'A') && (category != 'a'))`

Hint: the compiler is evaluation two statements `category != 'A'` ***OR*** `'a'`.

Since `'a` is non-zero, it will evaluate to `true` and mess up your logic

Also, you could simply this by taking the upper case of `category` and comparing it to 'A', thus needing only one comparison.

Comment: I ***strongly*** urge you to get an IDE with a debugger (Visual Studio, Eclipse, Code::blocks, Netbeans, etc) and learn to use the debugger. That will allow you to set a “breakpoint” in a line of code, then when you run your program, the debugger will stop when it  hits that line, an you can examine the values of your variables and figure out the problem for self

Comment: Wow thanks! I didn't realize my logic was all messed with the way I had it. 

Thanks :)!

Comment: No problems, but ***do*** get a debugger. It is the most important tool in your developer's arsenal. And, fell free to accept this answer, if it helped ;-) Doing so will help others who read the question in future

Comment: Yeah I will look into that, and thanks for the recommendations. I have been refreshing as fast as I could to hit answer for you. For some reason it's locked on a time before you can accept it.

Thanks again!

Comment: NP. Welcome aboard. I promise you that a debugger will mean that you won't have to ask here 80% or more of the question that you have, because you will be able to answer them yourself